# Android video play?

Tags: android, video, android-layout

I have the [vzzar video](http://view.vzaar.com/750184.download), when you paste it in your browser ,
its going to download the video in mp4 format , but i don`t know how to play that video using the link by buffering and playback it.

Comment: Do you want to load from URL or put this in raw folder or in sdcard and then want to load?

Comment: anyway i want to load and playback it

Answer (score 0):

Check out the sample code from [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code in your Activity:

```
 mVideoView.setVideoPath("http://view.vzaar.com/750184.mp4");
 mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
 mVideoView.requestFocus();
```

Comment: it is try to load in emulator and device , but it finally throws "sorry , can`t play this video"